# Unable to update Nvidia drivers on my Ubuntu 18.0.4 machine

Tags: drivers, nvidia, package-management, dependencies, ppa

i have recently switched from windows to Linux(Ubuntu 18.0.4) for good and am having some trouble updating my GUI.
i have attempted various methods i have found online to no avail. i seem to be encountering a dependency issue. when i try to install my recommended driver through the command 
`sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-430`

i am given the following error

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
nvidia-driver-430 is already the newest version (430.14 0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libnvidia-ifr1-430 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-430 but it is not going to be installed libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-430:i386 but it is not going to be installed
nvidia-driver-430 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-430 (= 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed

Recommends: libnvidia-gl-430:i386 (= 430.14-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)`

I'm rather new to this whole Linux thing, so I'm not quite sure as how to proceed here.